# Mongo db is not getting started

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to start my mongo but i have come across the following error

```
     W NETWORK [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
     E QUERY  [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0 .0.1:27017, connection attempt  failed :
     connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:229:14
```

I am trying to start my mongo but i have come across the following error
I had no idea about the error can any one please help me out of here...........

Comment: have you started server i.e. mongod?

Comment: i fixed it with the following command ........................................................sudo mongod -f /etc/mongodb.conf.........thank you

Answer (score 1):

You shoud start the mongod server first.

use this...

mongod --port 27017

then start